# Automapper: map properties manually

Tags: c#, automapper

I just started to use automapper to map DTOs<->Entities and it seems to be working great.

In some special cases I want to map only some properties and perform additional checks. Without automapper the code looks like this (using fasterflect's PropertyExtensions):

```
object target;
object source;
string[] changedPropertyNames = { };

foreach (var changedPropertyName in changedPropertyNames)
{
    var newValue = source.GetPropertyValue(changedPropertyName);
    target.SetPropertyValue(changedPropertyName, newValue);
}
```

Of course this code won't work if type conversions are required. Automapper uses built-in TypeConverters and I also created some specific TypeConverter implementations.

Now I wonder whether it is possible to map individual properties and use automapper's type conversion implementation, something like this

```
Mapper.Map(source, target, changedPropertyName);
```

---

### Update

I think more information is necessary:

I already created some maps, e.g.

```
Mapper.CreateMap<CalendarEvent, CalendarEventForm>()
```

and I also created a map with a custom typeconverter for the nullable dateTime property in CalendarEvent, e.g.

```
Mapper.CreateMap<DateTimeOffset?, DateTime?>().ConvertUsing<NullableDateTimeOffsetConverter>();
```

I use these maps in a web api OData Controller. When posting new EntityDTOs, I use

```
Mapper.Map(entityDto, entity);
```

and save the entity to a datastore.

But if using `PATCH`, a `Delta<TDto> entityDto` is passed to my controller methods. Therefore I need to call `entityDto.GetChangedPropertyNames()` and update my existing persistent entity with the changed values.

Basically this is working with my simple solution, but if one of the changed properties is e.g. a `DateTimeOffset`? I would like to use my `NullableDateTimeOffsetConverter`.

Answer (score 33):

If you just want to map only some select property than you have to do as below

```
// Create a map
var map = CreateMap<Source,Target>();
// ingnore all existing binding of property
map.ForAllMembers(opt => opt.Ignore());
// than map property as following
map.ForMember(dest => dest.prop1, opt => opt.MapFrom( src => src.prop1));
map.ForMember(dest => dest.prop2, opt => opt.MapFrom( src => src.prop2));
```

Comment: I don't know. I think after I updated my question, your solution is not what I'm exactly searching for, but apart from this it is looking good.

Comment: @krombi - you are looking something regarding mapping right ...i.e. mapping one select property of object to other object manually

Comment: Exactly. I know the names of the changed properties from the Delta<TDto> (equal names for DTO and entity) and I know the new values. And I want to map these properties/values to my existing entities.

Comment: @krombi - than above approch might work not 100% sure on that

Comment: I think I cannot use your approach, because ForMember takes an Expression as first param but I only have a string property name.
There is also an overload with a string as first param: map.ForMember("prop2", opt => opt.MapFrom( src => src.prop2)); but the second param is an action. And if I do not set the MapFrom(...) nothing is mapped.

Answer (score 12):

You can make some projection using **MapFrom** method - http://automapper.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Projection.html

```
Mapper.Map(source, target)
   .ForMember(m => m.Property, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.ChangedProperty));
```

For example (reffering to AutoMapper documentation):

```
// Model
var calendarEvent = new CalendarEvent
    {
        Date = new DateTime(2008, 12, 15, 20, 30, 0),
        Title = "Company Holiday Party"
    };

// Configure AutoMapper
Mapper.CreateMap<CalendarEvent, CalendarEventForm>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.EventDate, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Date.Date))
    .ForMember(dest => dest.EventHour, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Date.Hour))
    .ForMember(dest => dest.EventMinute, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Date.Minute));
```

Answer (score 5):

To do this with the latest version of `AutoMapper` first you should map the properties that you want then ignore the rest.

```
CreateMap<TSource, TDestination>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.FirstName, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.FirstName))
    .ForMember(dest => dest.FullName, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => $"{src.FirstName} {src.LastName}"))
    .ForMember(dest => dest.Prop, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.AnotherProp))
    // ...
.ForAllOtherMembers(opt => opt.Ignore()); // <=== Ignore The rest
```

Otherwise if you do `map.ForAllMembers(opt => opt.Ignore());` first, it will ignore all mappings even the mappings after this.

Answer (score 0):

If I read your question correctly, yes, as long as your destination (target) property matches your conversion.

So if I am going from a `string` to a `bool` for a `Status` of `"A"` or `"I"` (active/inactive), I can do something like:

```
.ForMember(dest => dest.Status, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Status == "A"))
```

And then when going the other direction, convert it back:

```
.ForMember(dest => dest.Status, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Status ? "A" : "I"))
```

A date example:

```
.ForMember(dest => dest.SomeDate, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.SomeDate.ToString("M/d/yyyy")));
```