# AutoMapper map only needed fields

Tags: c#, .net, automapper

I use AutoMapper for mapping classes. I am struggling with the Automapper syntax.
I have domain classes:

```
        public class Club
        {
            public int Id { get; set; }
            public string Name { get; set; }
            public DateTime OpenDate { get; set; }
            public IEnumerable<Team> Teams { get; set; }
        }

        public class Team
        {
            public int Id { get; set; }
            public string Name { get; set; }
            public string Department { get; set; }
            public IEnumerable<Player> Players { get; set; }
        }

        public class Player
        {
            public int Id { get; set; }
            public string Name { get; set; }
            public string Surname { get; set; }
            public int Age { get; set; }
            public string Address { get; set; }
        }
```

Also i have dto classes:

```
        public class ClubDTO
        {
            public int Id { get; set; }
            public string Name { get; set; }
            public DateTime OpenDate { get; set; }
            public IEnumerable<Team> TeamsDTO { get; set; }
        }

        public class TeamDTO
        {
            public int Id { get; set; }
            public string Name { get; set; }
            public string Department { get; set; }
            public IEnumerable<Player> PlayersDTO { get; set; }
        }

        public class PlayerDTO
        {
            public int Id { get; set; }
            public string Name { get; set; }
            public string Surname { get; set; }
            public int Age { get; set; }
            public string Address { get; set; }
        }
```

I have mapping setting from DTO classes in domain classes:

```
CreateMap<PlayerDTO, Player>();
CreateMap<TeamDTO, Team>();
CreateMap<ClubDTO, Club>();
```

I map `ClubDTO` class to `Club`:

```
...
 _mapper.Map(clubDto, club);
...
```

How do I setting mapping only `Player.Age` and `Player.Addres` instead of all fields all classes?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Automapper: map properties manually](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30123070/automapper-map-properties-manually) Basically, you should call `ForMember` after `Map`

Answer (score 1):

I believe you should ignore whatever properties you wouldn't like to be mapped, like so:

```
CreateMap<PlayerDTO, Player>();
    .ForMember(x => x.Id, x => x.Ignore())
    .ForMember(x => x.Name, x => x.Ignore());
    .ForMember(x => x.Surname , x => x.Ignore());
```

Take notice that this should be done during automapper configuration, not when you call the `Map` method.

Comment: Just beat me to it

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do something like this: `_mapper.Map(from, to).ForMember(x => x.MyProperty, opt => opt.Ignore());`

I would also suggest using `View Models`. This helps alot with `AutoMapper` For example:

```
public class Player
{
     public int Id { get; set; }
     public string Name { get; set; }
     public string Surname { get; set; }
     public int Age { get; set; }
     public string Address { get; set; }
}

public class PlayerViewModel
{
     public int Id{get; set;
     //more fields that you can use in your views
}
```

Comment: Not sure it will work like that as `Map` returns whatever "to" is, and that's not likely to have a `ForMember` method

Comment: Fair point. I have custom setup stuff for my AutoMapper so I am able to do that in the bottom of my View Models. I don't remember exactly how normal AutoMapper works, but you could be right

Answer (score 0):

```
 public class PlayerDTO
    {
       
        public int Age { get; set; }
        public string Address { get; set; }
    }

    var onlyAgeAndAdress=_mapper.Map(Player, PlayerDTO);
```

you will get only ages and adresses.